# Django: select values with max timestamps or join to the same table

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a simple Django models

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class ServerPropertie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server)
```

I want to add get_properties method to the Server model, which will return all last properties for current server. I mean it should return name and value of all properties names for current server and each uniq propertie name should have a value, which row has a maximum timestamp.

I can do it in raw hardcoded raw SQL(i use postgres):

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.value FROM environments_serverpropertie t1
JOIN (SELECT max("timestamp") "timestamp", name 
      FROM environments_serverpropertie
      group by name) t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp;
```

or in in python, but i believe that there exists pythonic solution. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you're using PostgreSQL, usual syntax for that is:

```
select distinct on (name)
    name, value
from environments_serverpropertie
where server = ...
order by name, timestamp desc
```

From [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html):

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
>   each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The
>   DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for
>   ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is
>   unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row
>   appears first.

You can see and try it in [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1a98a/1).

It's possible to translate this syntax to django, from [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in
>   order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should
>   apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query.

So in django it will be something like:

```
ServerPropertie.objects.filter(...).order_by('name', '-timestamp').distinct('name')
```