# Django queryset How to retrieve related fields with annotate()

Tags: django, django-models

I have this table:

```
id  supply   event_date   value_average
----------------------------------------
1     a      01-01-2018        5
2     b      02-01-2018        6
3     a      02-01-2018        7
4     b      03-01-2018        8
5     c      03-01-2018        9
```

I am trying to get the latest value for each supply based on event_date column. I can get the latest event, but I did not found a way to return the value_average as well.

```
values_average = Purchase.objects \
    .values('supply') \
    .annotate(last=Max('event_date')) \
    .order_by()
```

current return:

```
a        02-01-2018
b        03-01-2018
c        03-01-2018
```

expected return:

```
a        02-01-2018      7
b        03-01-2018      8
c        03-01-2018      9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that by following this answer:

[Django: select values with max timestamps or join to the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433314/django-select-values-with-max-timestamps-or-join-to-the-same-table)

```
values_average = Purchase.objects \
            .filter(farm=farm, supply__in=queryset) \
            .order_by('supply', '-event_date') \
            .distinct('supply')
```

It will only work with Postgres. The final result will be a normal queryset with the latest events. Just take care if your model has Meta ordering.

Django docs on this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add the value_average attribute to the values you want to return :

```
values_average= Purchase.objects.values('supply','value_average').annotate(last=Max('event_date'))
```

Comment: If I add value_average the result query will group by value_average too, and give me the wrong result.

with value_average:
...GROUP BY "event_event"."supply_id", "event_event"."value_average"

without value_average:
...GROUP BY "event_event"."supply_id"

Comment: Im not sure I get you but did you try to group by supply ? like this :
values_average= Purchase.objects.values('supply','value_average').annotate(last=Max('event_date')).groupby('suply')

Comment: As far as I know, .groupby() does not exists in the ORM. To group by something we must use values(). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values

Please, If I am missing something, could you point me out the docs related to it?