# How can I get latest record by queryset. like group by

Tags: python, django

## Data

| name | data1 | data2 | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iron man | ia | ib | 1630000000 |
| hulk | ha | hb | 1630000000 |
| hulk | hc | hd | 1630500000 |
| captain | ca | cb | 1630000000 |
| captain | cc | cd | 1630500000 |
| captain | ce | cf | 1630590000 |

## I want to get latest data each name

| name | data1 | data2 | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iron man | ia | ib | 1630000000 |
| hulk | hc | hd | 1630500000 |
| captain | ce | cf | 1630590000 |

like this

```
wish_data = [
    {'name':'iron man', 'data1': 'ia', 'data2': 'ib', 'create_date':1630000000},
    {'name':'hulk', 'data1': 'hc', 'data2': 'hd', 'create_date':1630500000},
    {'name':'captain', 'data1': 'ce', 'data2': 'cf', 'create_date':1630590000},
]
```

## I tried...

```
    Model.objects.filter(**conditions).values_list('name').annotate(cdate=Max('create_date'))
    
=> [('iron man', 1630000000), ('hulk', 1630500000), ('captain', 1630590000)]>
```

but i need to other columns...

## Q

Is it possible with ORM?
Or do I have to write the logic with for and if statements?

for example

```
wish_data = []
for name, data1, data2, create_date in Model.objects.filter(**conditions).values_list('name', data1, data2, 'create_date').order_by('-create_date'):
if name not in data:
    wish_data.append(
        {
            wish_data['name'] = name
            wish_data['data1'] = data1
            wish_data['data2'] = data2
            wish_data['create_date'] = create_date
        }
    )
```

Comment: Which database are you using with this project? You will need to get distinct data from and then group it using the name and latest data queries.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7020313/39296) may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. You can make use of `distinct` and `order_by` together in your django orm query to get your `wish_data`. The query would be something like this:

```
distict_avengers = Model.objects.filter(**conditions).distinct("name").order_by("name", "-create_date").values("name", "data1", "data2", "create_date")
```

If you will `print(distict_avengers)` then you will see the following result:

```
[
  {"name": "captain", "data1": "ce", "data2": "cf", "create_date": 1630590000},
  {"name": "hulk", "data1": "hc", "data2": "hd", "create_date": 1630500000},
  {"name": "iron man", "data1": "ia", "data2": "ib", "create_date": 1630000000},
]
```

Please note that using distinct on fields is not supported on SQLite and also when using `distinct` and `order_by` together the fields mentioned in the `order_by` must always begin with the fields mentioned in the `distinct`.

Comment: Thank you very much! You've been a great help :)
Thank you for telling me the precautions