# find set of values that have max occurrence in column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Print the name(s) and sid(s) of the student(s) enrolled in the most classes

**Enroll**

```
sid  class number
```

---

```
1     23
2     54
1     54
3     43
1     43
2     43
```

**student**
    sid  sname

---

```
1    sagar
2    kiran
3    ravi
4    vishal
```

**output**

```
sid   sname
```

---

```
1     sagar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586781/postgresql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column#588708 has a lot of good applicable material to this simple question, the terms you want to look for are aggregates (`GROUP BY`, `COUNT` specifically - and you can combine `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`) and `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group enrollments by students, order by count and use limit 1:

```
select s.id, s.name
from student s
join enroll e on e.sid = s.id
group by s.id, s.name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Note how you don't need the *select* `count(*)` - you may simply *refer* to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
SELECT <column_name> FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name>=
(SELECT <column_name>
 FROM (SELECT <column_name>, count(*) as cnt FROM <table_name> GROUP BY <column_name>) AS foo
 WHERE foo.cnt=(SELECT MAX(c) FROM (SELECT <column_name>,count(*) AS c FROM <column_name> GROUP BY <column_name>) AS bar)) limit 1
```