Optimize Finding Max Value per Year, String, Attribute
How do I get the rows for each year by scenario that are associated to the latest scenario for each year while being at-most prior month (future budgets & forecast scenarios exist as well)
Fields:

scenario (VARCHAR)

Distinguishes between budget or forecast

Format for forecasts (Jan Fcst, Feb Fcst, ..., Dec Fcst)
Format for budgets (Jan Adjusted Budget, Feb Adjusted Budget, ... Dec Adjusted Budget)


Forecast & Budget are updated every month for each month in current year (each unique forecast includes 12 rows (Jan - Dec).


a_year (VARCHAR in format 'FY%y') Ex: FY20, FY21, ... FY24

indicates year the forecast or budget applies to


a_month (VARCHAR in format '%b') Ex: Jan, Feb, ..., Dec

indicates the month the forecast or budget applies to


amount (DOUBLE)



+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Jan Fcst       | FY24 | Jan | 100 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Jan Fcst       | FY24 | ... | 150 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Jan Fcst       | FY24 | Dec | 80  |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Feb Fcst       | FY24 | Jan | 110 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Feb Fcst       | FY24 | ... | 180 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Feb Fcst       | FY24 | Dec | 103 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Jan Adj Budget | FY24 | Jan | 120 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Jan Adj Budget | FY24 | ... | 90  |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Jan Adj Budget | FY24 | Dec | 110 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Feb Adj Budget | FY24 | Jan | 130 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Feb Adj Budget | FY24 | ... | 200 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
| Feb Adj Budget | FY24 | Dec | 120 |
+----------------+------+-----+-----+

Each historical year has 288 rows per scenario when monthly forecasts/budgets are updated each month. (12 budgets & 12 forecasts, each containing 12 rows.
If the Forecast was last updated in Feb 2024 & Budget in Apr then the output should only include 12 rows in format:
+---------------------+------+-----+----+
| Feb Fcst            | FY24 | Jan | $$ |
+---------------------+------+-----+----+
| Feb Fcst            | FY24 | ... | $$ |
+---------------------+------+-----+----+
| Feb Fcst            | FY24 | Dec | $$ |
+---------------------+------+-----+----+
| Apr Adjusted Budget | FY24 | Jan | $$ |
+---------------------+------+-----+----+
| Apr Adjusted Budget | FY24 | ... | $$ |
+---------------------+------+-----+----+
| Apr Adjusted Budget | FY24 | Dec | $$ |
+---------------------+------+-----+----+


Would you confirm that this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/MLv6NeHk  accurately demonstrates the first 48 records?

You can parse the scenario to find the MonthNumber and ScenarioType https://dbfiddle.uk/8owouEj5 It should then be a simple matter to group by Scenario type and find the max MonthNumber.

You might also try a solution that uses Distinct ON. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586781/postgresql-fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-in-each-group

I used a CTE to find the max YearMonth for each scenario type
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT MAX(
  a_year||RIGHT('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(Substring(scenario,1,3), 'Mon')) as VARCHAR(2) ),2)
          ) as MaxYearMonth, 
           Substring(scenario,5,4) as ScenarioType
FROM Example
GROUP BY  Substring(scenario,5,4)
)
SELECT * 
FROM Example a
INNER JOIN CTE on CTE.MaxYearMonth = a.a_year||RIGHT('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(Substring(a.scenario,1,3), 'Mon')) as VARCHAR(2) ),2)
  AND CTE.ScenarioType= Substring(a.scenario,5,4)

fiddle

This solution uses DISTINCT ON
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Substring(scenario,5,4))
  Scenario, a_year||RIGHT('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(Substring(scenario,1,3), 'Mon')) as VARCHAR(2) ),2) as MaxYearMonth
FROM EXAMPLE 
ORDER BY Substring(scenario,5,4) DESC, a_year||RIGHT('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(Substring(scenario,1,3), 'Mon')) as VARCHAR(2) ),2)  DESC
)
SELECT * 
FROM Example a
INNER JOIN CTE on CTE.MaxYearMonth = a.a_year||RIGHT('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(Substring(a.scenario,1,3), 'Mon')) as VARCHAR(2) ),2)
  AND CTE.Scenario= a.scenario

Fiddle
